# iOS Swift can't re-show tabbar

Tags: swift

I have a tabbar controller in which there are two view controllers. One has navbar shown (VC1), one has navbar hidden (VC2). I push to VC2 using tabbar icon, then I navigate to VC3 from there via UIButton and now tabbar is hidden using

```
hidesbottombarwhenpushed = true
```

I then navigate BACK to VC1 using the following

```
dvc.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```

the problem is, no matter what I set to false for hidden, I cannt get the navbar or tabbar to reshow.

Can someone tell me the correct way to hide/show navbar/tabbar and programatically navigate froma  view back to a home page tab with hiding/showing navbar/tabbar?

Comment: In which function do `hidesbottombarwhenpushed = true`?  Where do you do it? VC1, VC2 or VC3?  And the same two questions for `hidesbottombarwhenpushed = false`?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann i set true it in storyboard (also tried programtically) for VC2, and set it false in prepareForSegue in VC3